# Why sometimes ClickHouse TopK() returns an array with some negative values?

Tags: clickhouse

My lookup column is a UInt64 type, so there shouldn't be any negative values.
And when I look for the minimum values, there are positive numbers.

But this query

```
SELECT topK(rid_hash) AS res
FROM tmp.table;
```

gives me an array like this
`[-304028290,-8216857390,-7321493392,-9889037088,24740950557, 24466788596,24439401901,-7343223091,-7386401297,-7376033234]`

So why the values in an array sometimes negative?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are storing negative values in a column with the UInt64 type. ClickHouse doesn't throw an error but stores the deviation from 0. In the case of UInt64, displaying this value in the table will show it as a positive number (max UInt64 + value). The `topK()` function returns an array, and the representation of values in the array looks as it was written. To turn the array into a table, you can use the `arrayJoin()` function:

```sql
SELECT arrayJoin(topK(rid_hash)) AS res
FROM tmp.table;
```